# Nuxt: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image: Nuxt: Unexpected token <]

I am working on a nuxt project, and I'm trying to build a map component using google maps and the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps. I have installed the plugin using npm

In my index.html page I have a normally working page that looks like:

```
<template>
   <div>

<br>
<br>
       <Card/>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
       <!-- <Googlemap/> -->
       <Panel/>
       <Four/>
       </div> 
</template>

<script>

import Panel from '~/components/panel.vue'
import Card from '~/components/detailCard.vue'
// import GoogleMap from '~/components/googleMap.vue'


export default {

  components: {

    Panel,
    Card,
//     GoogleMap
  }

}
</script>
```

When I Uncomment the 3 lines with Googlemap in them I get the error in the screenshot .

The Googlemap component is:

```
<template>
  <GmapMap
  :center="{lat:10, lng:10}"
  :zoom="7"
  map-type-id="terrain"
  style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
>
  <GmapMarker
    :key="index"
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    :clickable="true"
    :draggable="true"
    @click="center=m.position"
  />
</GmapMap>

</template>


<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: "MYTOKEN",
    libraries: "places"
  }
});

export default {

}

</script>


<style>

</style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you are missed transpile

https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/0985d475496083f2459db2960ba8f9317aab50ef/README.md#nuxtjs-config

```
transpile: [/^vue2-google-maps($|\/)/]
```

Comment: After adding your statement to the build object, the error is gone. However I do not see a map.

Comment: @user61629 hard to say what wrong else. create a codesandbox with reproductio

Answer (score 2):

Often it refers to the response from a request, where it was expecting a JSON object, but instead is returned HTML. The `<` refers to the first character in `<!DOCTYPE`... or similar.

Check the responses coming back from the APIs or other services you’re using.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the net tab in devtools. I'm not seeing anything from google. I've not used this api key before so its possible its somehow not active. Any thoughts on how to test that?

Answer (score 2):

Updating from Node 12x to Node 14x worked for me